# Persist selection after markjs instance.mark(tx)

Tags: javascript

I am using [markjs.io](https://markjs.io/) to highlight content on my page on-demand - but I want to retain any range selections once the marks are added - currently it's inconsistent between double-clicking on a word verses selecting a word using mousedown-move-up ... both seemingly random in their result

> [image]

I am marking the selections using the following javascript:

```
const selection = window.getSelection();
let findtx = selection.toString().trim();
var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector('#container'));
nstance.mark(findtx, {
    done: function() {
      instance.mark(findtx, {
        caseSensitive: false,
        separateWordSearch: false
      });
    }
  });
```

Runtime example available on https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/9guLs35w/20/